# Ubuntu Configuration for using Log4J Syslog

Tags: ubuntu, logging, configuration, log4j, syslog

I'm asking how to use the log4j syslog appender and which settings I have to do in Ubuntu. Currently nothing happen and no local1.log will be created...

My log4j.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
<!-- SYS LOG SETTINGS -->
  <appender name="syslog" class="org.apache.log4j.net.SyslogAppender">
      <param name="SyslogHost" value="localhost"/>
      <param name="Facility" value="LOCAL1"/>
      <param name="FacilityPrinting" value="true"/>
      <param name="Threshold" value="WARN"/>
      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{dd.MMM.yyyy HH:mm:ss} %-5p %m%n"/>
      </layout>
  </appender>

<root> 
    <priority value="trace" /> 
    <appender-ref ref="syslog" />
</root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

I use Ubuntu 13.4 with rsyslog and tried this configurations...
/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf

```
local1.*   /var/log/local1.log
```

and I read I have to activate the remote log, so that programs can write logs in syslog, but in which setting file I have to put the SYSLOGD="-r"? (former Ubuntu versions)